# Is HTTP basic authentication over SSL any less secure than 2 legged Oauth?

Tags: api, security, rest

I am building a REST API which needs to be reasonably secure - no payment details are passed, but I want to ensure accounts don't get hijacked, for instance.

I have looked at implementing 2 Legged Oauth, but I can't see any real advantage to just using basic auth over SSL (with a high entropy programmatically generated API key as the password)

Are they any scenarios where 2 Legged Oauth is more secure than HTTP basic auth over SSL?

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS is the complete HTTP data sent over a SSL connection.
The data sent through the HTTP basic auth is also encrypted if you use HTTPS.
Basically, so it should make no difference.
Bad could may be that you have to store the password on the client computer with HTTP basic auth.
With oAuth far as I know only a token is stored.

Comment: Any data over HTTP is not encrypted by default even when using Basic Auth

Comment: If you use HTTPS all HTTP data gets encrypted - even the http basic auth. HTTPS is not an own protocol its just HTTP over SSL.

Comment: Now that you have rewritten your answer I've removed my -1

Comment: Not sure that helps answer my question - are there any scenarios in which 2 legged Oauth would be more secure?

Comment: Its possible. Is it a desktop application? If the client pc gets infected by a trojan or so its maybe possible to read the password in plain text. If you use oAuth far as I know only a token is stored so the hacker dont get any passwords.

Comment: No, it's going to run on a server. In the oauth case I believe the consumer_secret could be exposed in exactly the way a password could, so I can't see a difference.

Comment: Sure but the user dont use the consumer_secret on other websites as password :)

Comment: It's ok - the password will be a programmatically generated API key.